# Storyboard segues and receiving memory warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, storyboard, segue

I am developing an application with iOS 9 based SDK , this is my first time I am working with Storyboards , I have 20 view controllers, each scene has Next / Previous buttons to go back and forward . I have a huge problem with going forward !. If I move from scene 1 to for example to scene 15 I received memory warning and then application crashes . I have searched and it seems there is method called `unwind segue` but it seems this is for going back ! it's something like `dissMiss` method .

I connect each scene with line in Interface Builder :

[image]

Here is segue's setting :

[image]

I would be grateful if you help me out .

EDITED :

I tried to present a view controller programmatically but result was the same ! .

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    WhatIsDino *vc = (WhatIsDino*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WID"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Does memory warning occurs the first time you go from 1 to 15, or does it starts to come a bit latter?

Comment: Storyboard segues should never point back to a previous scene. Instead, dismiss the presented view controller. The easiest way to do so is with an unwind segue.

Comment: @AbubakrDar memory going to occupied after each scene shows  .

Comment: @jlehr They all connect to each other ! I don't know what should I do !

Comment: Don't use segues to go backwards. That is wrong. Delete the backwards segues.

Comment: @Fogmeister the backwards is not my problem , I will delete them ok ! What about forwards?

Comment: Wait... You have 20 different views all set up with "next" and "previous" buttons?!

Comment: You need to be using something like a page view controller and have a single view controller that is used for all of the pages.

Comment: @Fogmeister yes , i cannot , each page has its own contents an data i cannot mix them in one single code and view !

Comment: That is exactly what you must do. How many different String classes would there be if each one could only display a single string? Make your content a property of the view controller that is passed in at run time. You should start with a basic tutorial. You are approaching this in a very wrong and bad way. The question here is not really valid. The problem is nothing to do with any segues or anything. The problem you are facing is because of a lack of understanding and knowledge of how to write apps. Start at he beginning. Learn about oop principles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it's a problem of wrong approach, and not the storyboard.

Let me guess, since before storyboard you used to change your app's `rootViewController` to the next/previous screen once you tap on the arrow button. So previous screen are released and deallocated from memory once you set a new `rootViewController`.

And now you're presenting every next view controller modally, which involved creating new `UIWindow` and loads all the hierarchy of you screen and **keeps previous underneath the new one** so it holds the memory and you're getting out of memory crash.

Well, you can do `rootViewController` approach with a storyboard too since it's just another way to manage your screens while development. Storyboard offers additional features like segues, static table view cells, general tint color and so on. `[UIStoryboard -instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:]` is the method you might find interesting.

But I'd rather recommend you to check out the `UIPageViewController`, it's like a container for the screens. Unfortunately, it cannot have the segues to your scenes (because of the special way segues work) so you have to use `-instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` method anyway. You can treat inner view controllers of `UIPageViewController` as you do with `rootViewController` before.

Comment: Sorry I just changes  a modal transition from segues to programmatically , but the result is the same ! ! !  have you any sample code or something ?

Comment: Using this code (Check my edited Question) , and same result

Comment: Yes, result indeed will be the same — your code does basically the same thing that segue did. You should instead use a `UIPageViewController` or get back to a `rootViewController` approach (the latter is not a good solution). Use `- setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:` method on a page view controller to update the screens — instead of your last line. There are plenty tutorials in the internet. Go over this one. You can ignore setting the delegate http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks it works fine now  ! I still received memory warning (not sure for cache or something else) but after receiving this message RAM will empty and then works fine.

Comment: For your further progress: check out this project, they did custom segue to work with `UIPageViewController` from storyboard directly. https://github.com/theothertomelliott/TEQuickPageViewController And Fogmeister are right — investigate, how can you unify your screens.

Comment: Would you please help me with this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32871462/uipageviewcontroller-and-removing-current-view-controller

Answer (score 0):

You can also navigate without segue and Its easy way I think.

If you want to navigate from Class1 to Class 2 then follow these steps.

1) In Class 1, Import Class2.

2) In your button Action, Write this code.

Class2 *next = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Class2 Identifier name"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];

Do not forget to give Identifier name in story board that is "Storyboard ID" in Attribute inspector of particular class.

No need to add Segue,Your storyboard would look clean.

Comment: No success , causes same issues

Comment: In One of my same case,It worked for me !! You may have to go with other solution.Good luck !!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding view controller after view controller with modal presentation. That causes each view controller to be added on top of the previous one, and all of them accumulate, using more and more memory.

Using a navigation controller and a push also piles the view controllers on top of each other.

You will have this problem if you use storyboards, nibs, or create the view controllers manually.

If you have a design where the user can move through a large series of view controllers then you probably want to dismiss the previous one before pushing/presenting a new one.

You can probably dismiss the previous view controller without animation and then present the new view controller each time you want to display a new one and avoid the memory issue. i'd have to experiment with it to get the effect I was after, but that's what I would suggest.

Comment: Thanks ! I think i have to change UIs and make a menu ! Or something like this